# Block input fields that were generated by React components

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, field

I'm very new in javascript and react programming language.
I'm block at a certain point of coding.

I use input field element from a react component that I wrote by my own.
Now, after created this, I use a loop to create my input fields form a categoriy list.

At this point my issue is to block these input field form a button. But by the fact that the input filed are generated by component instead of normaly created, how can I perform this blocking action from my button

This is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import WordInputProps from './WordInputProps';

const WordInput:React.FC<WordInputProps> = (props:WordInputProps) => {
    const {
        firstLetter,
        onWordChange
    } = props;

    return <input 
        placeholder={`${firstLetter}...`} 
        onChange={(e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => onWordChange(e.target.value)}
    />;
}

export default WordInput;
```

This is how I created my list item from my componant:

```
       const categories = [
        { 
          id: 2,
          name: "Something " 
        },
        { 
          id: 3,
          name: "Something else" 
        },
        { 
          id: 1,
          name: "Another thing" 
        },
      ];

 <ul style={{textAlign: "right", listStyleType: "none"}}>
            {categories.map((category:any) => {
              return <li>{category.name} <WordInput key={category.id} firstLetter={currentLetter} onWordChange={(word:string) => console.log(category.name + ": ", word)} /></li>
            })}
          </ul>
```

And finaly this is my button

```
<button onClick={() => console.log("Block button clicked")} > Block filed </button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocking the input field? Do you want to disable it, so you can't type anymore?

Comment: Exatly.  I want to disable all the input field list when I click my button in order to block typing and be redirected to another thing